# SQL Rename NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I searched and tried alot now, to figure out how to replace the name 'NULL' in a table, when I run this query:

```
SELECT 
YEAR(orderdate) AS Years,
       (CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN 'US' ELSE 'WORLD' END) AS region,
   SUM(netamount) AS TotSales
FROM orders o JOIN
     customers c 
     ON o.customerid = c.customerid
GROUP BY  (CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN 'US' ELSE 'WORLD' END),YEAR(orderdate) WITH ROLLUP;
```

I get this table: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBO1R.jpg

I want to replace the Nulls to 'SubTotal' respectively 'GrandTotal'.
I tried it with:

```
COALESCE(year(orderdate), 'Subtotal') years,...
```

and the same with 'IFNULL(...)' but instead of replacing the name, it makes an extra column with years where all the years are listed again and the NULL's are still remaining.

Any idea?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level, e.g. with a bit of PHP.

Comment: What do you mean by it makes an extra column?  COALESCE should work in your case... Also, not completely understanding how the above query produces NULL values for region -- it should equal either us or world...

Comment: @sgeddes The `ROLLUP` is causing the `null` values in the `region`

Comment: @bluefeet -- ah, thanks -- I didn't scroll over :)

Comment: Sorry, i should made a new line for that and mention it extra. The answer below is perfect btw. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is to wrap your query in another select and then replace the `null` values with a `COALESCE` or a `CASE` expression:

```
select 
    case 
        when Years is null and region is null then 'GrandTotal'
        when Years is null then 'SubTotal' 
        else Years end Years,
    coalesce(region, '') region,
    TotSales
from
(
    SELECT YEAR(orderdate) AS Years,
       (CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN 'US' ELSE 'WORLD' END) AS region,
       SUM(netamount) AS TotSales
    FROM orders o JOIN
         customers c 
         ON o.customerid = c.customerid
    GROUP BY  (CASE WHEN country = 'US' THEN 'US' ELSE 'WORLD' END),YEAR(orderdate) WITH ROLLUP
) d
```

Note, I am using a `CASE` expression since you have multiple columns you are comparing.

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a84ae/2)

Comment: @JOP See my edit, I realized that you had different values that you wanted so I changed to a `CASE`

Comment: Yes,I also just realized that you edited it. thats perfect. thanks alot :)

Comment: @JOP Yeah it would have been helpful if I fully read your question initially. :)

Comment: No problem. Your first answer was even helpful enough as a hint. Still really inconvenient just to rename NULL's. But that answer is perfect. Thanks :)

Comment: Could you explain me please, why it renames the NULL in years instead of region in the last line(where 'Grandtotal' is)? I thought maybe because you listed Years first, so i changed years and region in the first line of the case but no effort. Any explanation for that?

Comment: @JOP In my sample I am replacing the values in the `years` column with either `subtotal` or `grandtotal` but the region column is being replaced with an empty string. What do you want the `region` column to be replaced with?

Comment: I called it Overall. I know that I just need to name it in the coalesce part. My question belongs to this part:

    _WHEN Years IS NULL AND region IS NULL THEN 'GrandTotal'_

why does it rename the Null in years instead of region? Only explanation i have is cause this part: 

   else Years end Years,

cause of the years after end. Is it cause of that?

Comment: @JOP That `CASE` statement is on the `years` column so it will not impact the value in `region`. Does that help?

Comment: So as I assumed it's cause of the _end years_ ? that gives the impact to years and not region correct?

Comment: @JOP A `CASE` statement can only impact one column. If you want to change the value of `region`, then you will have to use a separate `CASE` statement.  The `END` is the closing of the `CASE` expression.